# json deserialize items into string format c#

Tags: c#, json, wpf

Not that much experience using `json`, I have read many topics on this but it seems like no one's got the same json structure that I'm working with so i cant seem to get the following items deserialized, basically i will be populating a listbox with all `bucketName` in the list as shown below, the json gets returned from a web request.

This currently holds all the json data:

`var responseString = new StreamReader(responseList.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();`

And this is the content it holds:

```
{
    "buckets": 
    [
        {
            "accountId": "someweirdid",
            "bucketId": "4a48fe8875c6214145260818",
            "bucketInfo": {},
            "bucketName" : "Kitten-Videos",
            "bucketType": "allPrivate",
            "lifecycleRules": []
        },
        {
            "accountId": "uuhhmthisisarandomid",
            "bucketId" : "5b232e8875c6214145260818",
            "bucketInfo": {},
            "bucketName": "Puppy-Videos",
            "bucketType": "allPublic",
            "lifecycleRules": []
        },
        {
            "accountId": "ahhhanotherid",
            "bucketId": "87ba238875c6214145260818",
            "bucketInfo": {},
            "bucketName": "Vacation-Pictures",
            "bucketType" : "allPrivate",
            "lifecycleRules": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the `bucketName` item to be populated in a listbox, please any help, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895168/12888024)

Comment: You can use https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp to convert your Json to C# Object.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting json object to C# and create a list which can be used to populate listbox

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```